# React - Best way to trigger a child method from parent/sibling component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new in React and maybe my logic here i a mess:
I have **Game** component and it has 2 childs: **Board** and **Timer**.

The **Board** have a button to start the game. When i start the game, i want to start the timer. There is a way to call directly the function to start the timer, from **Board**?
I tried to send a function to **Board** from **Game** and that function changes some states in **Game**, but i don't know how to trigger the startStopTime() of **Timer** (my idea was use useEffect() but i don't know if there is a more easy way)

Thanks for your help

Game.jsx

```
function Game(){

 return(
   <div>
      <Board>
      <Timer>
   </div>
 )
}
```

Board.jsx

```
function Board(){
  /* logic game*/
  return (
   <Button>Start game</button>
 )
}
```

timer.jsx

```
function Timer(){
  /* methods timer*/
  function startStopTime{ /* code*/}
  function resetTimer{ /* code*/}

  return (
   <div>{timeRunningGame}</div>
 )
}
```

Comment: what research have you done around this? this is a very common question, you just pass a prop from the parent, manage state on the parent that then passes an updated value to the other component

Comment: You can set a state in the parent component with `useState` then pass the state as prop to child components. Or use a state management library like Redux for one-way data flow.

Comment: I know how to pass states, but how do i trigger the function? Do i need to recode the function so is not a function?

Comment: You can't, but you can pass a callback update some state to start a timer to `Board` to put on the button, and pass a prop to `Timer` to start/stop from the common ancestor `Game`.

Comment: Can anyone post an example please, because i don't know how with an state can trigger the start. Thanks

Comment: i will do it with useEffect() (is working) but not sure if there is a better way to do it. useEffect(() => { if (props.timeStart){ startStopTime() }}, [props.timeStart]);

Comment: Since the declaration of state is in the parent component, the event for triggering the changes should be in there, too. Then pass the event function as prop to the child component. Read this documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html

Comment: @jstarnate i send a function from Game to Board. I click in Board and the game starts, and Game handle the state (parent of Board and Timer). But, i can't pass another function to Timer, because i don't click anything there, i just want to trigger it

Comment: @spunka Put the `startStopTime()` and `resetTimer()` functions inside `Game` then pass them as props to `Timer`. Then create two buttons in `Timer` that fire those events.

Comment: @spunka I suggest that you learn Redux or MobX for organized data flow so that you don't have to pass events and states from one component to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were on the right track thinking to use an effect in `Timer`.

Here's *an* implementation, others exist.

Timer.jsx

```
const Timer = ({ isRunning, onReset }) => {
  const [time, setTime] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = isRunning
      // if true, start timer
      ? setInterval(() => setTime(t => t + 0.1), 100)
      // else reset time back to 0
      : setTime(0);

    // provide cleanup function
    return () => clearInterval(timer);
  }, [isRunning]);

  return (
    <>
      <div>{Number(time).toFixed(1)}</div>
      {isRunning && (
        <button type="button" onClick={onReset}>
          Reset
        </button>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

Board.jsx takes an `onStartGame` callback function

```
const Board = ({ onStartGame }) => {
  /* game logic */
  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={onStartGame}>
      Start Game
    </button>
  );
};
```

Game.jsx Manages state of timer being started and passed

```
const Game = () => {
  const [isRunning, setIsRunning] = useState(false);
  const runTimer = run => () => setIsRunning(run);

  return (
    <>
      <Board onStartGame={runTimer(true)} />
      <Timer isRunning={isRunning} onReset={runTimer(false)} />
    </>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit game timer demo]

Comment: Thank you very much!! :)